# How write values to a string then return?

Tags: c#, xml, string, class

I have a timer that loops through following code every second. this code reads a few xml fragments one after another then prints them to the screen, it then repeats this a second later. output:

```
34,
23,
12,
```

What I want to do is to make write all the data to a string like 34,23,12 then returns it so that another class can use it. But if I put it(the string code , you'll see it below) under the `if (fragmentReader.Read())` code it doesn't work as it just does the same thing as the console.writeline above it: reads one of the fragments then writes to console, then the next fragment, it doesn't add all the values from the fragment into one string.

thanks

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var file = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("AIDA64_SensorValues"))
        {
            using (var readerz = file.CreateViewAccessor(0, 0))
            {
                var bytes = new byte[195];
                var encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
                readerz.ReadArray<byte>(0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                //File.WriteAllText("C:\\myFile.txt", encoding.GetString(bytes));

                StringReader stringz = new StringReader(encoding.GetString(bytes));

                var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment };
                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stringz, readerSettings))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        using (var fragmentReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
                        {
                            if (fragmentReader.Read())
                            {
                                reader.ReadToFollowing("value");
                                //Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadElementContentAsString() + ",");

                                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                                sb.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString()).Append(",");
                                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in every iteration of the loop you are creating a new stringbuilder object.  You need to create that object before your loop, then print the string after the loop.

What you want:

```
                 System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                 while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        using (var fragmentReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
                        {
                            if (fragmentReader.Read())
                            {
                                reader.ReadToFollowing("value");
                                //Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadElementContentAsString() + ",");


                                sb.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString()).Append(",");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `StringBuilder` **sb** is going out of scope. Try moving it so it is being created right after you enter your routine. And to add what @Stephan H stated your WriteLine needs to be placed after you have exited your loop, So that you get the proper output.

```
static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); 
    using (var file = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("AIDA64_SensorValues")) 
    { ....
```

Comment: With leaving the Writeline within the loop, the output would be 34, 34,23, 34,23,12,  Which is not the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `StringBuilder` and the `WriteLine` calls outside of the while loop. Since you are making a new `StringBuilder` each iteration of the loop you are getting a string with only 1 value (the value you just read).

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stringz, readerSettings))
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        using (var fragmentReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
        {
            if (fragmentReader.Read())
            {
                reader.ReadToFollowing("value");
                sb.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString()).Append(",");
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```